# How to host your own video and make an embedable link for viewing across the net

Tags: video, hosting

I want to host my own video, and then be able to view the video by having an embedable link

I dont know where to begin, so I need to know every little detail. For example, do i save the video file as a video file, an mp4 f.e., and then have some sort of video player so that i can view the embedded video??

Answer (score 4):

Upload the video to [Vimeo](http://vimeo.com/) or YouTube, let them do the hard work.

Okay, so you want to host it yourself. Convert the video to MP4/H.264/AAC format using Handbrake or `ffmpeg`, then embed a [Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/) player into your webpage. If MP4 doesn't work, try FLV. (YouTube serves both of these formats.)

If you want to avoid Flash, most popular browsers now implement the HTML5 [`<video>` tag](http://web.archive.org/web/20110726002026/http://diveintohtml5.org/video.html), which allows embedding videos directly. Unfortunately, the codec support is a very big mess of patents and ideologies, and those who choose to use `<video>` have to resort to [publishing several different formats](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody) including a Flash-based player.